# Owl Carousel not working in some pages - Opencart

Tags: opencart, owl-carousel

I have used Owl Carousel in my footer. The carousel works fine in most pages like Home, Products, etc. but doesn't work in some pages like Register, Affialiate, Information pages, etc.

I checked console and i got the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

Figured out the js and css for carousel are not included in header for those pages.

I know about getScripts() and getStyles() functions of document.php that are called in header.php. How do I get the js and css available for all the pages of my website? I can hardcode it but is there any other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open:

```
catalog/controller/common/footer.php
```

add:

```
$this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css');
$this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js');
```

this will add owl carousel files to all pages.

Comment: Yeah but i do get these files with getScripts() and getStyles() function in most pages, just wanted to figure out first why are they not available in all pages before hardcoding like this